# Maintain Session and Authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

I have developed a `CRUD operation project in Laravel` and integrated it into the already existing CorePHP project using an iframe.

The existing CorePHP project has a session and `authentication mechanism` implemented.

The `CRUD operation` should be performed by the Admin only. Since there is no authentication mechanism in the project that I have developed, the URL for the CRUD operation project can be accessed by anyone.

Can I use the same session and authentication mechanism from the existing project or should I develop the new session and authentication in Laravel project that I have developed?

Which would be the better option?

Comment: I guess it depends on the nature and niche of the main site, and on what  does the CRUD manage.

Comment: CRUD manages the creation, retrieval, update and deletion of the employees. This is the task which should be done by the authorized users only.

Comment: So I guess average user shouldn't see the iframe. I would definitely handle the permissions by the outer application. (Or even better: both)

Comment: Yes, the average users shouldn't see the iframe. What do you mean by the outer application here? You mean to say that you would develop the permissions with the help of Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way you can use this package handled authentication and authorization mechanism
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: I have also the scenario where the admin can give the authority to behave as a admin to the existing users.

Comment: this seems to get more complicated. why don't you build the CRUD in the main app?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but the main app is very old and it has been developed by other developers. Since I have already developed the CRUD using the Laravel and implemented it using the iframe. I thought it will be better option just to maintain the session and authentication mechanism rather than developing the CRUD in the main app from the beginning onwards. And I have developed the project in Laravel so that it will be easy for the validation and other stuffs.